# JQuery-File-Upload BlueImp file upload EXIF orientation rotation

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, jquery-file-upload

I use BlueImp-jQuery-fileupload with MVC5/C# backend to upload JPGs.
On the client I need a pre resize and on the server I need the JPG with its full original EXIF for further processing.
The problem is with tall photos. I've tried several combinations with the options. Non gave me everything ....

```
        imageOrientation: false,
        previewOrientation: false,
        previewThumbnail: false,
        imageMaxWidth: 1111,
        imageMaxHeight: 1111,
        disableImageResize: false,
        imageQuality: 0.8
```

Ends up not corrected (sideways) on the server.

```
        imageOrientation: true
        previewOrientation: false,
        previewThumbnail: false,
        imageMaxWidth: 1111,
        imageMaxHeight: 1111,
        disableImageResize: false,
        imageQuality: 0.8
```

Gets them double corrected (?) (head down) on the server.

```
        imageOrientation: true
        previewOrientation: false,
        previewThumbnail: false,
        imageMaxWidth: 1111,
        imageMaxHeight: 1111,
        disableImageResize: true
        imageQuality: 0.8
```

Gets the orientation OK but skips the resize.

Here is the full code:

```
<script>
    var $form = null;
    $(function () {
        $form = $('#fileupload').fileupload({
            dataType: 'json',
            imageOrientation: false,
            previewOrientation: false,
            previewThumbnail: false,
            imageMaxWidth: 1111,
            imageMaxHeight: 1111,
            disableImageResize: false,
            imageQuality: 0.8
        });
    });
    $('#fileupload').addClass('fileupload-processing');
</script>
```

Can anyone help resolve?

Answer (score 1):

Try to perform a test this way:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
   imageQuality: 0.7,
   imageForceResize: true,
   disableImageResize: false,
});
```

Comment: Sorry for my later response. I will try that.